# Bootstrapping 95% CI gives different values depending on how it's coded

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval, coefficients, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap the 95% confidence interval of the coefficient for a linear mixed model. I was following the code listed here https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html.

Here is a subset of my data.

```
Exdf <- structure(list(Plant.ID = c("CE90151", "CE90218", "CE90494", 
"CE90882", "CE91012", "CE90053", "CE90641", "CE90920", "CE90213", 
"CE90229", "CE90328", "CE90485", "CE90726", "CE90881", "CE90931", 
"CE90983", "CE90137", "CE90282", "CE90869", "CE90885"), FlowerNumberStd = c(-0.260418578891271, 
-0.260418578891271, 0.0105779306706318, -0.802411598015076, -0.802411598015076, 
1.63655698804205, -0.531415088453174, -0.260418578891271, 0.281574440232535, 
2.44954651672776, -0.260418578891271, 0.281574440232535, -0.531415088453174, 
-0.802411598015076, -0.531415088453174, -0.802411598015076, 1.09456396891824, 
0.281574440232535, -0.802411598015076, 0.281574440232535), RelativeFitness = c(0.102591221575886, 
0.615547329455315, 1.23109465891063, NA, NA, 5.0269698572184, 
0.102591221575886, 0.410364886303543, 2.56478053939714, 7.181385510312, 
0.102591221575886, 0.923320994182972, 0, NA, 0, NA, 3.590692755156, 
1.74405076679006, NA, 1.53886832363829), greenhouse.position = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("bench_2", "bench_3", "bench_4", "bench_5"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code that I ran:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)


rsq <- function(formula, data, indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  mod <- lmer(formula, data = d)
  return(coef(summary(mod))[2])
}

results <- boot(data = Exdf, statistic =  rsq, R=100, formula = RelativeFitness ~ FlowerNumberStd + (1|greenhouse.position))

boot.ci(results)
tidy(results, conf.int = T) # these both give the same CIs
```

But if I try to calculate them using this code, they are different. I don't understand what this code is doing that is so different from the above.

```
mod <- lmer(RelativeFitness ~ FlowerNumberStd + (1|greenhouse.position), data = Exdf)

tidy(mod, effects = "fixed", conf.int= T, conf.method = "boot", boot.type = "perc",nsim =100)
confint(mod)
```

I don't think it's related to the type of confidence interval I'm running (i.e. bca vs perc). Even though these values differ greatly probably because I only ran it 100 times. I ran the bootstrap 1000 and 10000 times on my full dataset (~ 500 obs) and the confidence intervals were all ~(0.8, 1.6) using the first set of code but (1.1, 1.3) using the second. I'm trying to understand why they are different and which set of values is correct because eventually I want to use LMMs that include more parameters and also non-linear models.

Comment: Don't implement your own bootstrap procedure for lme4 models. Study `help("bootMer")`. Also, `confint` by default calculates CIs from the likelihood profile, see `help("confint.merMod")`.

Comment: Also, **the first two arguments** to the statistic function **must be `data` and `indices`**, eventually by other names. `rsq <- function(data, indices, formula)`.